# What is wrong with my for...in loop? / How to reference object names? (codecademy, javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, reference, for-in-loop

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: "(206) 555-5555",
        address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052'],
    },

    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number: "(408) 555-5555",
        address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
    }
};



var list = function(friends) {
    for (var i in friends) {
        console.log(friends[i]);
    }
};
```

I'm asked to log the names of the two objects to the console, but I'm confused about how to do this. Codecademy doesn't make it clear enough for me to understand. Can you? Desired output:

```
bill
steve
```

note: i do NOT want friends[i].firstname, I want the names of the objects friends[i].

Comment: Pretty sure Steve doesn't live there any more...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am pretty sure Steve "lives" no more... :p

Answer (score 1):

In this case `i` itself is the property name

```
for (var i in friends) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
for (var i in friends) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

This is because `for`...`in` loops through the **keys** of the object.

Also, I suggest a different variable name, such as `friend` instead of `i`, because `i` usually means a number or index.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke the function `list`, like this

```
list(friends);
```

And in the `list`, you just have to print the name like this

```
var list = function(friends) {
    for (var name in friends) {
        console.log(name);
    }
};
```

In the ES5 supported implementations, you can simply use

```
Object.keys(friends);
```

If you use underscore.js, you can use `_.keys`, like this

```
_.keys(friends);
```